# Scraping data from the table using Xpath and PHP?

Tags: php, xpath, web-scraping

I want to extract the data from the table below and the markup of the table is given below.I'm using Xpath to extract data from the table but other suggestions are also welcome.

```
      <div style="clear:both;" id="showPrice">
      <br>
      <table cellspacing="1">
         <tbody>
             <tr>
                 <td width="50px" style="text-align: left" class="tdhead">SN</td>
                 <td width="650px" style="text-align: left" class="tdhead">Companies</td>
                 <td width="20px" class="tdhead">Trans</td>
                 <td width="50px" class="tdhead"> Max Price</td>
                 <td width="50px" class="tdhead">Min Price</td>
                 <td width="50px" class="tdhead">Closing Price</td>
                 <td width="50px" class="tdhead">Total Shares</td>
                 <td width="50px" class="tdhead">Amount Rs.</td>
                 <td width="50px" class="tdhead">Prev. Closing</td>
                 <td width="20px" class="tdhead">Diff.</td>
                 <td width="50px" class="tdhead">Diff. %</td>
                 <td colspan="3" class="closing-price">
                     <table>
                         <tbody>
                            <tr>
                               <td colspan="3">365&nbsp;days</td>
                             </tr>
                             <tr>
                               <td width="50px" class="closing-price-lighter">Max Price</td>
                               <td width="50px" class="closing-price-lighter">Min Price</td>
                               <td width="50px" class="closing-price-lighter">Avg</td>    
                             </tr>
                         </tbody>
                     </table>
                     </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style="background-color: #A61A00">
                       <td style="text-align: center;color:white;">1</td>
                       <td style="text-align: left;padding:3px;">
                          <a href="viewcompany.php?symbol=ACEDBL&amp;id=177" style="text-decoration:none;color:white;">Ace Development Bank Limited</a>
                       </td>
                       <td class="numeric-data">3</td>
                       <td class="numeric-data">269.00</td>
                       <td class="numeric-data">264.00</td><td class="numeric-data" style="background-color:#99CCFF;color:black;">264.00</td>
                       <td class="numeric-data">495</td>
                       <td class="numeric-data">131,405</td>
                       <td class="numeric-data">265.00</td>
                       <td class="numeric-data">-1.00</td>
                       <td class="numeric-data" style="background-color:#99CCFF;color:black;">-0.38</td>
                       <td class="numeric-data" style="background-color:#99FFFF;color:black;">281</td>
                       <td class="numeric-data" style="background-color:#99FFFF;color:black;">102</td>
                       <td class="numeric-data" style="background-color:#99FFFF;color:black;">150.15</td>       
                   </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
         </div>
```

I want only the data after the **closing-price** class. The data which I require is the text and the numeric value from the following **td** of the **tr**:

```
                       <td style="text-align: left;padding:3px;">
                          <a href="viewcompany.php?symbol=ACEDBL&amp;id=177" style="text-decoration:none;color:white;">Ace Development Bank Limited</a>
                       </td>
                       <td class="numeric-data">3</td>
                       <td class="numeric-data">269.00</td>
                       <td class="numeric-data">264.00</td><td class="numeric-data" style="background-color:#99CCFF;color:black;">264.00</td>
                       <td class="numeric-data">495</td>
                       <td class="numeric-data">131,405</td>
                       <td class="numeric-data">265.00</td>
                       <td class="numeric-data">-1.00</td>
                       <td class="numeric-data" style="background-color:#99CCFF;color:black;">-0.38</td>
                       <td class="numeric-data" style="background-color:#99FFFF;color:black;">281</td>
                       <td class="numeric-data" style="background-color:#99FFFF;color:black;">102</td>
                       <td class="numeric-data" style="background-color:#99FFFF;color:black;">150.15</td>       
                   </tr>
```

I tried following expression but could not get the result:

```
  //div[@id='showPrice']/td[preceding-sibling::td[@class='closing-price']]/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do somethin like this:

Point it to that particular `<tr>` tag:

```
$html_string = file_get_contents('http://www.sharesansar.com/today.php');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html_string);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$values = array();
$row = $xpath->query('//div[@id="showPrice"]/table[1]/tr[2]/td');
foreach($row as $value) {
    $values[] = trim($value->textContent);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($values);
```

The results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => Ace Development Bank Limited
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 269.00
    [4] => 264.00
    [5] => 264.00
    [6] => 495
    [7] => 131,405
    [8] => 265.00
    [9] => -1.00
    [10] => -0.38
    [11] => 281
    [12] => 102
    [13] => 150.15
)
```

Comment: I got no result with the above expression. This i the site from where I wanted to extract the data:http://www.sharesansar.com/today.php

Comment: @user3127109 you should have added the link to the question, since this is more of a concrete example of what you are trying to parse. check my revision, tried and tested, should work now

Comment: I tried it in console in google chrome but no result. By the way I want the data of all the companies listed in the page like your above result!!